# how to simulate the size effect with DFT theory?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-size-effects

I am considering simulating the size effect of nanoparticles, the size expands from 0.2nm to 50nm, but when trying to build the model, I am not sure how to reflect the size correctly, for example, if I wanna build a supercell which is 50nm long, then it would contain thousands of atoms. It is gonna very expansive to do DFT simulation for such a big supercell.
My question is:
Is there any method that allows me to analyze the size effect without building a huge supercell?

Comment: What properties of the nanoparticles are you studying? For some properties like formation energies, reactivities etc., the property can be decomposed as a sum of contributions from the various surface atoms and the bulk atoms, which reduces to a few small-cell periodic slab calculations plus a bulk calculation. For other properties like optical spectra, this is not possible.

Comment: The answer is no. Any kind of calculation needs structural input data. Without building a cell, you have nothing to calculate.

Comment: If you do nanoparticles, why would you even use a supercell? Codes that employ an atomic orbital basis are able to compute systems with thousands of atoms, and you don't need to worry about ghost interactions.